# React: router link with param not working

Tags: reactjs, router, link-to

[image]

My problem is passing ${file.id} to link, but when I navigate to that link, I only receive like this:
[image]

the ${file.id} is not get correct value.
But when I inspect the key of row, it can render correct.

[image]
What are my mising?

Thanks

Comment: Thats because you are not using backticks (\`) , use `to={\`something/${key}\`}`

Comment: Thank @ShubhamKhatri. It works now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using the wrong quotes. String interpolation is not possible with single quotes or doublequotes. You have to use the backtick `

So

`<Link to={'api/admin/blobManager/${file.id}'} />`

should instead be

`` <Link to={`api/admin/blobManager/${file.id}`} /> ``